# How to get partial exact value from string in table field MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I got table promos, with field store_id_list (VARCHAR). what i want to achieve here is i want this promo can be available into multiple store in 1 record, instead using multiple record, the store_id_list value is the list of store_id separated by comma (ex: 1,4,5,7,)

Now, i want to get record of table promo, where i have single store_id value, ex: store_id=5 how can i do that in MySQL? can i do that in single query? if using LIKE then more likely i can get 15 or 45 instead of 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice is to normalize your tables, and have a db-record per store/promo. But it can be done like this:

Make sure you have commas at the beginning and end of the column value, like this:

```
store_id_list : ,1,4,5,7,
```

And then query like this:

```
... where store_id_list like '%,5,%'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [`FIND_IN_SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function.  For example:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE FIND_IN_SET('5', store_id) > 0;
```

Comment: find_in_set should be more than 1 string, but my question is in 1 string, so i cannot use this, but thanks anyway!